# making my html site compatible

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Following code will show html file that i want to make compatible

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>*****</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/dashboard.css' %}"  rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
   <link href="{% static 'style_sample.css' %}"  rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="{% static 'script_sample.js' %}"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
{% block content %}
<div id="header>">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" ><img src="{% static "bootstrap/css/logo4.png" %}" alt="" style="margin-top:-5%;"/></a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
 {{ user.first_name }}</a></li>

        <li><a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out\" ></span>Logout</a></li>

      </ul>

    </div>
 </div>
</nav>
</div>


<div class="menu_sample top_mar">
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;">Dashboards</span></li>
         {% for Dashboard in dashboards %}
<li><a href="{{ Dashboard.d_url }}">{{ Dashboard.d_name }}</a></li>
           {% endfor %}
          </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="content pushed top_mar">
      <button onclick="toggleMenu()"><span id="menu-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" id="glymphi" style="margin-left:24%;"></span></span></button>
</div>

<div style="margin-left:-1%; margin-top:3.5%; height: 625px;" class="col-sm-9" >
<iframe width="100%"  height="95%" name="iframe_a" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>


{% endblock %}
  </body>

</html>
```

using bootstrap and css, css i am using is as follows

```css
/* Styles go here */

.menu_sample {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: left 1s ease-out;
  margin-left: -2%;
  margin-top: 150%;
}

/*transition*/
.top_mar {
    margin-top: 25%;
}

/* on toggle*/
.content.pushed {
  left: 225px;
}

.hide {
  transform:translateX( -100px);
}
```

i can see the odd things when i reduce or increase the size of the browser.
need help to make it compatible for all sizes..

Comment: @KevinPaulKalis, like divs will collide and it will not remain the same as in normal display size

Comment: Simple answer is use media queries.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai how to use media queries

Comment: And change your Doctype to <!DOCTYPE html>. Its better to use the new html5 then the old declarations. [HTML 5 Reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/)

Comment: @Vijay Kumar Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535814/how-to-use-media-queries-in-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using Bootstrap, but declaring the HTML 4.01 doctype...You should use the HTML5 doctype `<!doctype html>`. Since your using Bootstrap, the best example would be to view the source code of getbootstrap.com and you will see they are using the HTML5 doctype. The HTML5 doctype will give the best compatibility as most modern smart phones/tablets have focused on it.

Bootstrap handles the media queries for you, unless your doing custom coding.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples Provides various layout examples. Find the one closest to what your wanting, and use it as a base. Then build off of it and customize it. Get everything laid out the way you want it before worrying about colors and other style related issues.

Using the Bootstrap columns will give you what you want.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">left side</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">right side</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are 12 cols that make up 1 row. 12 is the same as 100% of the parent. So 6 is 50% of the parent (which is "row"). You must put cols inside a row, or other columns. With the example I just gave above, on smaller devices the right side will drop nicely under the left side. You can replicate this by resizing your browser window.

Everything you need is already in Bootstrap. I suggest learning it, learning the columns, and put your site together using the tools Bootstrap gives you instead of trying to hack your own. Your have loaded Bootstrap, so use it!

You can create an entire site with everything Bootstrap gives you. Then your style sheet only has to make them look the way you want with colors, font sizes, etc. Your style sheet basically is a color scheme to override the built in Bootstrap theme.

Bootstrap handles header, navbar, sidebar, footer, main content area, everything for you if you use the provided classes that comes with it. Then, if you need the header to be thicker or thinner, different background color, you override it with your stylesheet.

**Lastly:** Looking over your question, you really aren't clear what is going on. I recommend taking more time and rewording your question. Your page looks like a navbar, with a button, and an iframe.. If your talking about what is inside the iframe looking messed up, then that is another problem, as it's another site with it's own source code that WILL scrunch if it isn't responsive. If you don't own the page in the iframe, then there isn't anything you can do about it.

Comment: i am talking about navbar, i am using onclick icon to toggle navbar. The navbar and onclick icon is behaving odd for different page size

Comment: What is wrong with the built in responsive navbar that comes with Bootstrap? When you resize the Bootstrap navbar, it changes to a mobile menu with the [=] looking button, that drops down your menu items. No extra coding is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To make site compatible you can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) - [this introduction](http://cssmediaqueries.com/what-are-css-media-queries.html) is quite good

check these links for more reference:
[Link1](http://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints)
[Link2](http://blog.templatemonster.com/2014/10/14/css-media-queries-for-all-devices-and-browsers-including-ie7-and-ie8/)

Or you can try `%` instead of `px` for width etc.