# Banner auto fit to mobile users

Tags: html, css, mobile, banner

I have a banner that is set to center
What i want to do it how to make it auto fit for mobile?
here's my CSS code.

```
#banner{
background: transparent url(banner.jpg) no-repeat;
width: 870px;
height: 300px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border: 5px solid #fff;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="banner"></div>
```

Image  [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcJ5v.png)

Help?

Comment: It has obvious syntax error. Missing `{` . To fit in mobile, you should use media queries.

Comment: forgot to put it.. how though? How to use media queries?

Comment: Media Queries: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: I know but.. It make my mind muddled. I didn't get it..  sorry

Comment: [stackoverflow: How to use media queries in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535814/how-to-use-media-queries-in-css)

Comment: @LeeWise follow better tutorials in MDN instead of W3Schools.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use media queries. By default the element will be 100% width then use a media query to set the width once the window is wide enough.

```css
#banner {
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 870px){
  #banner {
    background-color: #0f0;
    width: 870px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner"></div>
```

Comment: Forget to put meta viewport? Also, if you use media query, it's quite rare to use fixed width. Use width percentage or `vw` instead.

Comment: Can you give any more info on what exactly isn't working?
I've edited my code above to better illustrate the media query in action. You'll need to expand the snippet then resize the browser window width to see the color change.