# How do I re-range the order of divs when resizing the screen?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a page to render using react-bootstrap on desktop like this:

```
 <Row>
   <Col xs={12} md={8} className="a">
   </Col>
   <Col xs={6} md={4} className="b">
   </Col>
   <Col xs={6} md={4} className="c">
   </Col>
 </Row>
```

In the UI, looks like this

`|   |_b_|
| a |_c_|
|   |   |`

I'm trying to make my order like the following when screen size is less than 786 px like in mobile or tablet, so it will be:

`|_b_|
| a |
|   |
|___|
| c |`

I have tired to use `xsPull` or `mdPull` or `flex-direction: column` and re-ordering in CSS , but none of these work. Am I missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535814/how-to-use-media-queries-in-css

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use Bootstrap?

Comment: @rileyjsumner I know the media query, but I don't know what I miss in html or css

Comment: @hmiedema9 Well, not really. I tried to use react-bootstrap, but it was getting worst. Maybe I didn't use properly. What and how to use react-bootstrap?

Comment: I would just recommend using Bootstrap. It already has all of the media queries done using Grid Layouts. Check out: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to consider is the logical reading order, which is probably closer to the mobile view. On wider viewports where the user can rely on visual hierarchy and make choices about what to read and in what order -- that's where you want to do the reordering. So begin mobile first, and create the elements in logical order:

Determine a breakpoint where you simply reassign the [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items) property under the flexbox model. There are a number of ways you could do this, but something like this would work, using your shorthand as simple class names:

```
@media (min-width: 40em) {
    .b { order: 2; }
    .a { order: 1; }
    .c { order: 3; }
}
```

Of course you'd need to do more than to achieve the layout, but that achieves the simple reordering needed.

Comment: I have updated my post and I tried your way, but not working. Am I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get what you are looking for, use this. The order property is also good to use if you need to change the order like @denmch suggested.

**HTML: **

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.item {
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbqeytdw/1/)

Comment: Yea, I have tired his way but it's not working. I have also updated my question